# Group array i can not understand this question who can help me

Tags: arrays

groupBy(array, fn)

> Returns an object of the elements of `array` keyed  by the result of `fn`
> on each element in array. The value at each key will be an array of
> the corresponding elements, in the order they appeared in initial
> array.

Comment: What language/library is this?

Comment: It groups the elements in the array, categorized by the result of `fn`. Results of `fn` are used as keys to provide the groups. For example, if `array` is a list of strings, and `fn` is a function that gives you the first letter of a string, then all the strings that begin with `a` will be in the `a` group (keyed with `a`), etc. The return is probably a hash. If this is Javascript, you can read this for reference: [groupBy in javascript](https://www.consolelog.io/group-by-in-javascript/) (just a little internet searching goes a long way).

Comment: Javascript map reduce filter

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which language you're using this in, but 'Group By' is a pretty common functionality in many languages and they generally work like this:

1. You start with a collection of something, let's say animals
2. If you want to group the animals by some condition, you have to define that condition so it can be verified for each animal in the collection
3. Use the group by function on the collection with the required condition to get the subsets that represent the groups of animals that satisfy the required condition

*Examples*

Here's a set of animals { bear, beluga, deer, moose, tiger, wolf  } and we want to check if an animal eats meat or not. You'd get two subsets: { bear, beluga, tiger, wolf} which contains animals that do eat meat and { deer, moose } with the animals that don't eat meat.

You can also group them by any arbitrary conditions such as by the number of letters in their names. This time, you would get three subsets: { bear, deer, wolf } (4 letters), { beluga } (6 letters) and { moose, tiger } (5 letters).

At any rate, I don't know what language you're programming in but it's very likely that `groupBy(array, fn)` takes in an array such as the set of animals, and that `fn` is a function that returns `true` or `false` when testing an element of `array` against the required condition to be put in a group.

Answer (score 0):

This example might help, using lodash and JS.

```js
const values = [1, 100, 200, 3, 5, 7];

function classifier(x) {
  if (x >= 100) {
    return "big";
  } else {
    return "small";
  }
}

console.log(_.groupBy(values, classifier));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

outputs

```
{ small: [ 1, 3, 5, 7 ], big: [ 100, 200 ] }
```

The `groupBy` applied function `classifier` to each element of `values` in turn. It then creates an object whose keys are all the different values that the classifier returned (here, small or big). The values of these keys is an array containing the corresponding elements, so for example `small` has all the values for which classifier returned 'small'.